# Copy nifi templates from one HDF to another

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using HDP 2.5 and HDF Version 1.2.0.3.0.0.0-453. Can anyone tell me how to export and import nifi flows from one HDP to another HDP.

I know how to export template into an .xml file and then import to new HDP. 
However, i am looking to understand can i move all the templates in one go ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple and lame way of doing this. Since it's very easy, I found no one has ever mentioned it!

[image: Go to main windows and create a new template]

**Go to main windows and create a new template. Save with a new name. Templates will be saved in NiFi Templates**

[image: Nifi templates on right menu]

> You can now locate the saved template and download it :)

Comment: This is the regular way of exporting importing a template, but the question was how to export all the templates at the same time, I don't see how this solve this problem.

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu select the view you want to download. For me this the main view which has a lot of sub views. Therefore, idea is come out to all template-view and export :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the Nifi documentation covers the export features of templates

Comment: anything you found? @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

You can't move all the templates in one move.

A better, faster and easyest approach is to use NiFi Registry to manage the flow, so if you have your HDP and HDF connected to the same NiFi Registry, you are going to be able to import things in one click.